# Instead of a div being shown, the form is sent

Tags: php, forms

The following should output a div if the data is not entered in the input fields or if the passwords don't match, but it does not happen:

```
<?php
$data = $_POST;
if(isset($data['action_signup'])){
    $errors = array();
    if(trim($data['email'])==''){
        $errors[] = 'Введите email';
    }
    if(trim($data['login'])==''){
        $errors[] = 'Введите имя пользователя';
    }
    if($data['password']==''){
        $errors[] = 'Введите пароль';
    }
    if($data['enterpassword'] != $data['password']){
        $errors[] = 'Пароль введен не верно';
    }
    if(empty($errors)){
        //Все заебись
    }else{
        echo '<div class="error_div">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
    }
}

?>
```

Form:

```
<form action="/Register.php" method="post">
                    <div class="containerForTextRegister"><a class="register">РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container_inputs">
                        <input class="register_input_email" name="email" placeholder="e-mail" required type="email" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo @$data['email'];?>">
                        <input class="register_input_login" name="login" placeholder="login" required maxlength="12" value="<?php echo @$data['login'];?>">
                        <input class="register_input_password" name="password" placeholder="password" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$" maxlength="30">
                        <input class="register_input_enterpassword" name="enterpassword" placeholder="enter password" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$" maxlength="30">
                        <div class="buttons_container">
                        <button class="button_entrance"><a class="text_button_entrance">войти</a></button>
                            <button class="button_register"><a class="text_button_register" name="action_signup">регистрация</a></button>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

A div window should appear, but the data is just sent and that’s it. Help, I will be very grateful

Comment: You are going to need to use Javascript to validate the form before you sent it and change the visibility or display of a div if the input is not valid.  You cannot do this with PHP alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your html code `<button class="button_register"><a class="text_button_register" name="action_signup">регистрация</a></button>`  to

Or
`if(isset($data['action_signup']))` to `if(isset($data['email']))`

like

```
<?php
$data = $_POST;
if(isset($data['email'])){
    $errors = array();
    if(trim($data['email'])==''){
        $errors[] = 'Введите email';
    }
    if(trim($data['login'])==''){
        $errors[] = 'Введите имя пользователя';
    }
    if($data['password']==''){
        $errors[] = 'Введите пароль';
    }
    if($data['enterpassword'] != $data['password']){
        $errors[] = 'Пароль введен не верно';
    }
    if(empty($errors)){
        //Все заебись
    }else{
        echo '<div class="error_div">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You can also use the button name. But do not use in anchor tag (<a>).